# How to debug remote connection failure to a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql

I'm a new user and I hope to get it right.

However I've a problem with a remote access to postgresql.

I've changed `postgresql.conf` (`listen_addresses = '*'`) and I've changed `pg_hba.conf` (I've added `host all all 10.0.0.1/32 trust`) but I can't do remote access into database.

How could I find its reason?

Comment: An error message would be a good start.  Log entries, packet captures, firewall rulesets, networking config, and all the other things necessary to diagnose the fault might also be important.

Comment: Please include the command line and output you see on the remote host when you attempt to contact the database server.

Answer (score 1):

On the line in `pg_hba.conf`, the address field value `10.0.0.1/32` allows *only* a single client with IP address 10.0.0.1. Usually specify the mask as `10.0.0.0/16` to allow all clients with IP addresses `10.0.x.x`.